# What does -> mean and why are they in this folder?

Tags: macos, gruntjs, symlink

I noticed that installing the grunt-cli did this.  It looks like a symbolic link or something similar.

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        39 Jan  9  2016 grunt -> ../lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        28 Nov  3  2015 heroku -> /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel  23369552 Dec 23  2015 node
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        38 Jan 10  2016 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxr-xr-x   1 a     admin        64 Mar 22  2016 subl -> /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel        75 Apr 28 06:32 vbox-img
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel        77 Apr 28 06:32 vboxwebsrv
```

More importantly, why is it doing this?

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
```

Comment: All node modules are stored in a separate location and /usr/local/bin/ will be in the PATH so the file can be found easily from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the `->` indicates the file is a "symbolic link" ( aka "`symlink`" ) — the `l` in front of the permissions is also an indicator of it's type. Essentially filename `a` redirects to filename `b` at it's location ... `a -> b`.

You can create a symlink simply by doing:

```
$ ln -s <target> <original>
```

When creating a symlink it's the reverse of `a -> b`. ( In other words, while creating the symlink you would "link symbolically (ln -s) `<target>` (b) to `<original>` (a)" )...

Why `/usr/local/bin/grunt` goes to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt` is something you'd have to ask the developer, although my guess is that by doing:

```
$ grunt
```

...it's much more convenient than doing:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
```

If the symlink wasn't indicated as it is in `/usr/local/bin` then you'd be using the latter...

Comment: Correct. If the file is in a directory owned by root you'll need to use `sudo ln -s` ...